# How to use react router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am building an application that has different pages and I was wondering how I would be able to restructure my routess i want to load login component on '/' and i have this.props.history.push("/homepage") on login page which open up the homepage on successful login i have a navbar in the homepage with different links would i address loading the components in the homepage when links are clicked and i want the navbar to stay only in the homepage and load component next to it.I am new to react.Whats the best solution to this kind of scenario.

navbar code

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import jwt_decode from "jwt-decode";
import { Link, withRouter } from "react-router-dom";

class Navbar extends Component {
  logOut(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    localStorage.removeItem("usertoken");
    this.props.history.push("/login");
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <ul style={navBarStyle} id="sidenav-1" className="sidenav sidenav-fixed">
        <li>
          <h1 className="center-align" style={{ fontSize: "30px" }}>
            Hello
          </h1>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to="/profile">
            <i style={linkStyle} className="material-icons ">
              person
            </i>
          </Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="https://twitter.com/MaterializeCSS" target="_blank">
            <i style={linkStyle} className="material-icons ">
              book
            </i>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to="/searchcourse">
            <i style={linkStyle} className="material-icons">
              search
            </i>
          </Link>
        </li>
        <li style={linkStyle}>
          <a href="" onClick={this.logOut.bind(this)}>
            <i style={linkStyles} className="fas fa-sign-out-alt" />
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    );
  }
}
```

homepage

```
class Homepage extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    document.title = "Dashboard";
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Navbar />
        <div className="container">
          <div>
            <h3>Dashboard</h3>
            <hr />
          </div>
          <div className="col" />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

this is my app.js

```
<BrowserRouter>
<Route path="/login" component={Login} />
          <Route path="/register" component={Register} />
          <Route path="/homepage" component={Homepage} />
          <Route exact path="/profile" component={Profile} />
          <Route exact path="/searchcourse" component={SearchHelper} />
          <Route exact path="/item" component={CourseItem} />
</BrowserRouter>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use nested routes. Keep Homepage specific sub-routes inside Homepage component. That way route `/homepage` will open up Homepage Component.

Inside Homepage you can have Navbar and the child routes of homepage like :

`/homepage/profile`, `/homepage/item` etc.

Here is one article to dig deep: https://medium.com/@marxlow/simple-nested-routes-with-layouts-in-react-router-v4-59b8b63a1184